# how to change QCheckBox text label color in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox, qcheckbox

I'm unable to change the color of `Qcheckbox` in **QT**, can somebody help me with code to change color of check box text label.
I have tried `Qpalette`.. And im using **QT4.7.4** version..

Answer (score 9):

You could use [stylesheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop).

e.g:

```
checkBox->setStyleSheet("QCheckBox { color: red }");
```

For more details check the [style sheets in Qt Reference](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/stylesheet-reference.html) and the [stylesheets documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/stylesheet.html)

Comment: style sheet also not working...Is there any alternative method?

Comment: You mean to say `setStyleSheet` (capital S on "Sheet")?

Comment: Those links are dead

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
QPalette p = myCheckBox->palette();
p.setColor(QPalette::Active, QPalette::WindowText, green);
myCheckBox->setPalette(p);
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem using various versions of Qt5 (5.2, 5.4). To do it with style sheets I had to use the Pseudo-States properties: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states

Example:

```
myCheckbox->setStyleSheet("QCheckBox:unchecked{ color: red; }QCheckBox:checked{ color: red; }");
```

Setting both states changed the colors for me. It seems there are some oddities like this in the stylesheet and palette system so keep your eyes out for them and try a few different things (i.e. selectors, pseudo-states, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like for some widgets you have to force using non-system "widget-engine". For checkbox it can be done by setting borders to none. So checkbox's style looks like:

```
QCheckBox {
   border: none;
   color: white;
}
```

Similar behavior is required by other widgets. Some style-properties do not disable native look. For example QPushButton (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html)