# Change text color of QCheckBox in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qcheckbox

I want to change the color of the text next to a `QCheckBox`.
I have tried these 2 questions:

[how to change QCheckBox text label color in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153945/how-to-change-qcheckbox-text-label-color-in-qt)

[Changing QCheckBox text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761517/changing-qcheckbox-text-color?lq=1)

None of those solutions seem to be working for me.

```
p = QtGui.QPalette(self.chkbox[i].palette())
p.setColor(QPalette.Active,QPalette.WindowText, QtCore.Qt.red)
self.top_grid.addWidget(self.chkbox[i],i+2,0)
```

**Edit 1:** Here is the minimal working code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    top_grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    chkbox=[]
    chkbox.append(QtGui.QCheckBox('1'))
    chkbox[0].setStyleSheet("color: red")
    chkbox[0].setToolTip('<b>ABC</b>' )
    top_grid.addWidget(chkbox[0],0,0)
    w.setLayout(top_grid)    
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I do this, the color of the `ToolTip` changes to red, but the text next to the checkbox remains black.

**Edit 2:** If I add the line

```
app.setStyle('cleanlooks')
```

It works. The default style is `sgi`, where, for some reason, the text color doesn't change. It worked with all the other styles.

Comment: Minimal code seems to work fine.

Comment: @SaileshSriram The color of the text doesn't change for me. Only the ToolTip becomes red.

Comment: The palette example is incomplete: you must also do `self.chkbox[i].setPalette(p)`.

Comment: @Tanay. What platform are you testing this on?

Comment: @ekhumoro I added the setPalette line, but it still didn't show. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @Tanay. Try changing the widget style. If that makes no difference, it's probably something specific to your Ubuntu setup. What DE are you using?

Comment: It worked with a different style! I'm using Unity. Thank you :)

Comment: @Tanay, please post the code minimal code that worked for you, for future visiters. I was using Windows when posted the answer, but now I tested it on Linux mint 17, it didn't work.

Comment: @qurban Please check if it works now.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by using style sheet:

```
for chbox in self.chkbox:
    chbox.setStyleSheet("color: red")
```

Comment: "'QCheckBox' object has no attribute 'SetStyleSheet'" is thrown when I try that.

Comment: The first letter of all the methods should be lower case

Comment: Sorry, I should have noticed that!
It still doesn't work. The text color doesn't change.

Comment: Post the minimal working example, so that I can debug it

Comment: I have added it to the question

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, it worked fine here. The color was red for text